# Undefined opnMP function when calling a openMP shared library from python

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, ctypes, .so

I want to write a small c++ - code with openMP, compile it to .so and call it from python using. The c++ source is -

```
from ctypes import *
import ctypes

c_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("libtest.so")
c_lib.openmp_test()
```

and the cpp file is as follows -

```
#include<iostream>
#include<omp.h>
void openmp_test()
{
    std::cout<<"in c++";
    int threads = omp_get_max_threads();
    std::cout<<threads;
}
```

I create the .so file using -

```
g++ -c -fPIC -fopenmp test.cpp -o test.o
g++ test.o -shared -o libtest.so
```

However running the python file gives me the error -

```
undefined symbol: omp_get_max_threads
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should  add the library omp into  library dependency of program.

```
  g++ test.o -shared -lomp  -o libtest.so
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. Could you please show how to do that, I was not able to understand the solution. Also I though .so files are precompiled files, so we just need to invoke them, am I correct ?

Comment: I dont know where to make what changes. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I add -lomp when you make a share object.

Comment: will try it, give me a minute. UPDATE -  I tried running g++ test.o -shared -lomp -o libcmult.so
 it says cannot find -lomp

Comment: You should install omp package.

Comment: Just realized that and installed it sorry for that... It does create .so without any errors.. However, it now says undefined symbol openmp_test()

Comment: You should add extern "C" in your functions. Because ctypes just work with c function.

Comment: I tried that too but still did not work ... Update - I rebooted and its working now.. wonder why it was not working before

Answer (score 0):

I provide for you complete solution:

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<omp.h>
 extern "C"
 {
 void openmp_test()
 {
     std::cout<<"in c++";
     int threads = omp_get_max_threads();
     std::cout<<threads;
 }
 }
```

After that you should make share library with :

```
g++ -c -fPIC -fopenmp test.cpp -o test.o
g++ test.o -shared  -lomp -o libtest.so
```

and then run your python script of course you should provide full path of your library.

Comment: If you need more help please let me know.